# Industrial-Standard UDP Broadcast on Windows?

Tags: mdns, zeroconf, dns-sd

I would like to use the UDP boardcast to tell the lan devices here is a XX-device. It is the same scenarios as the mDNS/Zeroconf for the printer. 
  However, as my know, Windows supporting with zeroconf is bad. The most simple way to implement zero-conf on windows is to use the Bonjour library. But, Bonjour runs as a service, it brings the end-user unfriendly. 
  Could any one give me some suggestion to achieve this goal ? What protocol could be my choice ? Or, is there a zero-conf libraries working on Windows (both 7 and 10) ? The broadcast and discover both run on Windows. 
  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just investigating this as well. What I've found is that [DnssdServiceInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.servicediscovery.dnssd.dnssdserviceinstance?view=winrt-18362) seems to be the way to go when it comes to UWP apps. Exactly how to use it I've not been able to figure out yet.
Hope this helps.
/Fredrik

Comment: Thank you, it looks like MS only provides the C# calling interface.